# Problems with newtxmath math fonts

Tags: newtxmath

I use `newtxtext` and `newtxmath`.

The problems are as follows:

1. `$\triangleright$` yields something like `\mathcal{F}`. With
   `\show\triangleright` I get `\triangleright=\mathchar"2246`
2. The exclamation point doesn't show up when you type `$n!$`.

Comment: Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, possibly starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. In this way we can copy-paste the code and look at the problem without resorting to wild guesses about what you are doing.

Comment: In particular, do tell us which document class you use and which packages you load in addition to `newtxmath` and `newtxtext`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A minimal example is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[mtphrb]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{newtxmath}
\begin{document}
$\triangleright$ $n!$
\end{document}
```

By removing `\usepackage[mtphrb]{mtpro2}`, I solved the problem.

Comment: The piece of information that you were loading both `mtpro2` and `newtxmath` is absolutely crucial, and it should have been mentioned in the original query. Without this piece of information, did you expect *anyone* to come up with a diagnosis, let alone a cure?

Comment: How can one close a question, or suppress it when it is a silly question?